# Masking or Clipping an Image to fit View in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm working on an app in React Native for both Android and iOS.

I have a View that I would like to display an image with no white space. My View is sized using Flex, so it is dynamic in sizing based on the screen size. I would like the centre of the image to be in the centre of the View. If the width is larger than the height, I would like the width of the Image to equal the width of the View, with the top and bottom of the Image being clipped off. If the height is larger than the width, I would like the height of the Image to match the height of the View with the sides being clipped off.

I have tried to use 'contain' and 'cover', but they don't seem to achieve what I would like. I could also just not be setting my styles up properly. This is what I have right now:

```
<Image style={{ flex: 1, width: width, height: height, resizeMode: 'cover' }} 
       source={require('../../images/Road03.png')} 
/>
```

Width and height are equal to the width and the height of the window:

```
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

I've also tried to look for libraries that achieve this, but I haven't found any that let me size the mask.